# Angular Material: Weird behaviour of $mdDialog (not closing)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I've started a really little project to play a bit with Angular + Angular Material. I've been trying to implement a $mdDialog, but it doesn't work. The dialog can be opened by the designated button, but the closing part doesn't work. I press on the button that should close the dialog, nothing happens for some seconds, then it closes and the button for opening the dialog can't be pressed anymore... I really have no idea what's going on here. These are the files:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body layout="row" ng-app="SomeApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" style="width:200px">
      <md-list layout="column">
        <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Items</md-subheader>
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="$parent.activeItem = item">
          {{item}}
        </md-list-item>
        <md-button ng-click="askNewItem($event)" class="md-raised" layout-align="center center">ADD NEW ITEM</md-button>
      </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>
    <md-content>
      This is {{activeItem}}
    </md-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

, and:

```
angular.module( 'SomeApp', [ 'ngMaterial' ] )
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.activeItem = "1";
    $scope.items = [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7"
    ];

    $scope.askNewItem = function($event) {
      var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
      $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        parent: parentEl,
        targetEvent: $event,
        template:
          '<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="hide()" class="md-primary">CLOSE</md-button>'
      });
    };

    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
      $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
      };
      $scope.close = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
      };
    }
  });
```

I just can't find the mistake... Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code directly into [plunker and it works](http://plnkr.co/edit/rGHAS3Qk69161m12l3Mb). So there's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Maybe check console in your browser for other potential error messages.

```
//would not let me post plunker link without a code block
```

Maybe you're using an outdated version of Angular or Angular Material.

Comment: I see... I'm using the code inside an Electron app, but basically, this script should work in Electron if it works in Chrome. Also, I can't find anything on Google mentioning Electron + Angular doesn't work, the integrated console doesn't throw anything either... Edit: I also use the most current versions of everything, Angular[-animate, -aria] 1.4.8, Angular-Material 1.0.0-rc4 (also tried with 0.11.x and 0.10.x)

Comment: Just to be sure... did you include ngAnimate and ngAria? Required by Angular Material...pretty sure you did, if the dialog already opens. But beside that, would need to see your other code to see what could be causing it. Did you try the plunker, is that how it works on your app?

Comment: Yes I did include them, and the plunker worked, that is the exact same code I am using, there are no other files except a package.json and a style.css, but I already checked, the style.css, if left out, doesn't change anything (except for the width of the sidebar)

Comment: I should maybe add that if the I press the button to close the dialog, the dialog not only closes after like 5 seconds, and the button to open it is not clickable anymore, but also, the items in the list aren't clickable anymore either, like every ng-click broke during the process

Comment: I just found out that this problem only occurs in the prebuilt version of Electron, which probably makes it a bug of Electron. I submitted an issue and will post an answer on this question once the problem is resolved.